# How to write down function in migration file (knex.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-migration, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have been wondering about how to write `down` function in migration file. Ideally, it should be exactly opposite of what we are doing in `up` method. Now suppose I wrote `up` function to drop `unique` constraint on a column, added some new rows(having duplicate data) to a table and now I want to rollback the migration. Ideally, I would write `down` method to add a unique constraint again on the column but migration would not rollback as a table now contains duplicate data. 
So my questions are -

- What to do in such a situation?
- How to write `down` function in migrations?
- Can I keep the `down` function blank in such a situations?

Thanks.

Comment: you should not insert data on `up`. Inserting data is related to `seeding`.

Comment: @FazalRasel he never said that adding rows was part of the migration file and sometimes it is perfectly fine to do so. Seed files are used usually for repetitive tasks and migrations for tasks that are run just once.

Comment: @FazalRasel Yes, as Mikael said, I am not inserting any data on `up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't write down functions at all and just leave them empty.

I never rollback migrations and if I want to get to earlier DB state I just restore whole DB from backups.

If I just want to put unique constraint back, I will write another up migration which fixes duplicate rows and then adds unique constraint back.

I know that many people is using rollback between tests to reset DB, but that is really slow way to do it.

Comment: As you said you would write another migration which _fixes duplicates_. How would you fix the duplicates in migration? What if I have performed a `soft delete` on previous data and want to keep it in a database along with adding a unique constraint?

Comment: @HarshalGangurde You can choose what ever method works the best for you. Instead of complete unique index, you can create partial unique index, which just ignores soft-deleted rows (we do this for our archived rows). Other way is to move soft-deleted data to other table or change data inside soft deleted rows in a way that constraints are not failing. There is no correct answer to that, depends on application.